# C++ Lock-free strand implementation - race condition?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I have implemented Boost's equivalent to a strand (boost::asio).  For reasons out of the scope of this question, it is not possible to use the boost implementation.

My original implementation uses an std::mutex. Upon conducting some performance analysis, this original implementation has turned up to be a hotspot - namely requiring transition from user/kernel space (because of mutex).

In light of that, I've tried my luck at writing a lock-free implementation using TBB's concurrent_queue.  Nonetheless, I believe there is a race condition because it appears that after a few minutes of running, works stops being submitted (and I believe there is work queued). Now, there could be a problem elsewhere in my code.

I keep questioning whether it's possible without a mutex, because there are 2 conditions to check against:

1. State -> Running?
2. Num of work/tasks available

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
#include <assert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

#include <tbb/concurrent_queue.h>


namespace
{

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
constexpr bool is_background_service(const strand::service_policy policy)
{
    return policy == strand::service_policy::SERVICE_BACKGROUND;
}

} // End anonymous ns

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class strand final
{
public:

    enum class service_policy
    {
        SERVICE_DEFAULT = 0,
        SERVICE_FOREGROUND = 1,
        SERVICE_BACKGROUND = 2,
    };

private:

    typedef std::pair<std::function<void()>, service_policy> pair_type;

public:

    strand() = delete;

    ~strand() = default;

    ////////////////////////////
    explicit strand(thread_pool pool, const service_policy default_policy) :
        m_pool(std::move(pool)),
        m_default_policy(default_policy == service_policy::SERVICE_DEFAULT ? service_policy::SERVICE_FOREGROUND : default_policy)
    {
        // What does a default policy here mean??
        assert(default_policy != service_policy::SERVICE_DEFAULT);
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    void post(const std::function<void()> &f, const service_policy policy)
    {
        CB_ASSERT_MSG(!!f, "Bad function!");

        pair_type pair = {f,policy};

        const bool bPost = (++m_nCount) == 1;

        if (bPost)
        {
            // Thread pool parameters:
            // 1. Work task
            // 2. True = background, false = foreground.
            m_pool.enqueue_async(
                [this, pair{std::move(pair)}]() { execute(pair); },
                is_background_service(get_scheduling_policy(policy)));
        }
        else
        {
            m_q.push(std::move(pair));
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    void execute(const pair_type &pair)
    {
        try
        {
            if (BOOST_LIKELY(!!pair.first))
            {
                pair.first();
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            post_next();
            throw;
        }

        post_next();
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    void post_next()
    {
        bool bPost = (--m_nCount != 0);

        pair_type pair;
        if (bPost && m_q.try_pop(pair))
        {
            // Note: Even if this is a pool thread, we queue
            // this work because we aim to be fair (even if it comes
            // at the expense of performance).

            // Thread pool parameters:
            // 1. Work task
            // 2. True = background, false = foreground.
            m_pool.enqueue_async(
                [this, pair{std::move(pair)}]() { execute(pair); },
                is_background_service(get_scheduling_policy(pair.second)));
        }
    }

private:

    ////////////////////////////
    service_policy get_scheduling_policy(const service_policy policy)
    {
        switch (policy)
        {
            case service_policy::SERVICE_DEFAULT:
            {
                return m_default_policy;
            }
            default:
            {
                return policy;
            }
        }
    }

    // Lock-free concurrent queue.
    tbb::concurrent_queue<pair_type> m_q;

    // Number of items in queue.
    std::atomic_size_t m_nCount{0};

    // Thread pool to which work is sent.
    thread_pool m_pool{};

    const service_policy m_default_policy;
};
```

Environment:

- Ubuntu 17.10
- GCC 7.2
- C++ 14

Comment: If you suspect a race condition, why don't us use `-fsanitize=thread`?

Comment: The most likely cause of a data race seems to be the `m_nCount` member. Operations on the object itself might be atomic, but you use it (or `bPost`, which depends on it) in many places. Its value may change between your updates to it and the checks on it to determine which code path to take.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you need the two checks you mention. Doesn't the fact that a task is available imply the state is "running"?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I did actually give the thread sanitizer a try upon a recommendation. The problem I quickly discovered is that it reports problems in TBB queue. It's difficult to see the wood from the trees.

Comment: @bnaecker Maybe. I might be making this harder than it needs to be..

Comment: Using parameter type `const std::function<void()> &f` in critical part is questionable. At least you enforcing copy even when it is not necessary.

Comment: @Slava Noted. Thanks.